# Integral involving $\ln$ and $\gamma$

Tags: integration, euler-mascheroni-constant

I want to know if its possible to have a closed form of this integral $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln(kx) dx$$
I know that if k = 1 then the integral is equal to $-\gamma$ but i want to find a generalized form

Comment: $\log(kx) = \log(k) + \log(x),$ and so $I(k) = \log(k) + I(1)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$I(k)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln(kx) dx$$
$$I´(k)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac x{xk}dx$$
$$=\frac 1k\int_0^\infty e^{-x} dx$$
$$=\frac 1k$$
$$\implies I(k) = \ln(k)+c$$
$$I(1) = 0+c=-\gamma$$
$$\implies c=-\gamma$$
$$I(k) = \ln(k)-\gamma$$

Comment: This is overkill. See my answer.

Comment: @PeterForeman No need to criticise someone else’s answer if it’s right; no one is competing for a $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: I know, it's just that this answer assumes the OP understands differentiating under the integral etc. Whereas the answer can be obtained by only knowing log laws.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln{(kx)}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(\ln{(k)}+\ln{(x)})\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\ln{(k)}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln{(x)}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\ln{(k)}-\gamma\\
\end{align}$$